# Fetch Highest Parent Key for a JSON value using jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, key, fetch

I have a json

```
{
 "yes": 
      {
       "en": "Yes",
       "de": "Ja"
      },
 "no": 
      {
       "en": "No",
       "de": "Nein"
      }
}
```

I want a java function using jackson that can find the highest key possible for a particular json value.

For Instance, if I passed value as `Nein` -> then `no` Key which is at the top level should be the output. How can I accomplish this in java??

Comment: Can you elaborate more clearly what is that you want?

Comment: @MS90 I have done the possible changes!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could try something like following:

```
   public static void getRootNodeOfJSONObject() throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonString = "{\"yes\":{\"en\": \"Yes\",\"de\": \"Ja\"},\"no\": {\"en\": \"No\",\"de\": \"Nein\"}}";
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        JsonNode jsonNodeRoot = objectMapper.readTree(jsonString);

        for (Iterator key = jsonNodeRoot.fields(); key.hasNext();) {
            String text = key.next().toString();
            if(text.contains("Nein"))
            {
                String rootElement = text.substring(0, text.indexOf("="));
                System.out.println("Root element: " + rootElement);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        getRootNodeOfJSONObject();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try JsonPath (https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath).

Focus on "Predicates" section.

If you need any help let me know.